# Changing font in CSS

Tags: css

I need to change the font to Georgia. The current css is:

```
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
```

I use this with the icon, but I want change font to Georgia and to do that i tried this:

```
font: Georgia normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
```

But this doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The font is set to fontawesome. Can you include the html of what you're trying to change?

Comment: Best solution is to understand what are you changing, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font?v=example

Comment: Do this `font: normal normal normal 14px/1 Georgia;` ... and since you repeat the defaults (`normal`), you can cut that down to `font: 14px/1 Georgia;`

Comment: IT work for text but it delete the current fa-icon

Answer (score 2):

You can't have 2 fonts for the same element. You will need to move the text HOME to a separate element.

e.g.

CSS

```
.home {
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span class="home">HOME</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font Family fontAwesome has nothing to do with Font Family Georgia

you should declare like so

`font: normal normal 14px/16px Georgia,sans-serif;`

first `normal` -> `font-weight` ( light normal bold etc.)

second `normal` -> `font-style` ( normal, italic, oblique )

`14px` - > `font-size`

`16px` -> `line-height` ( i suggest you use a bigger line height than the font-size, not like you set in your example )

`georgia,sans-serif` -> `font family` , georgia being a `family-name` and sans-serif being a `generic-family`

You can use 2 font-family on a single tag but will not work as you intend to do it . It would work like this :

> The font-family property can hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.

```css
p {
  
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
h1 {
 font: normal normal 14px/16px Georgia,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>
some heading
</h1>
<p>
Some text
</p>
```