# change Font in HTML/CSS file

Tags: html, css, font-family

I downloaded the source code of this online portfolio project but I don't know how to change that weird font family. can anyone help? https://github.com/akashyap2013/PortFolio_Website

Comment: not sure if i got you but check this https://github.com/akashyap2013/PortFolio_Website/blob/master/css/fonts.css

that where he define his font

Comment: What did you try? Did you do any research before asking? Because there's a post titled [Changing font in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44648605/215552) that probably answers your question. In any case, please take the [tour] and read [ask], where it says, "...**copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."

Answer (score 0):

To change the font, you can add the `@font-face` in the CSS.

For example:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

If you use another font like `Roboto`, you may need to add its source link:

```css
@font-face{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    src: 'source link here',
}
```

Or you may just set in the text itself like this:

```css
span {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

p {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<span>Helvetica</span> <br>
<p>Serif</p>
```

In that repository, the font style is defined in: https://github.com/akashyap2013/PortFolio_Website/blob/master/css/fonts.css

Answer (score 0):

Go to your CSS folder and to the fonts.css

```
/* @font-face */ 

@font-face{
font-family: "Roboto";
src: '../fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf';
}
```

then change this to any font you want. just download a new font pack online and replace the font folder. Then route that new font folder this css.

i.e

```
/* @font-face */ 

@font-face{
font-family: "super-cool";
src: '../fonts/super-cool/super-cool-Regular.ttf';
}
```